# Installing python library to a custom location?

Tags: python, django, installation

I want to use a couple of third party django packages for my application. So, I want to install each package locally for that application (or my whole project).

The python [custom installation instructions](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#custom-installation) look a bit scary - how do I do this as simply as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put the library module into your project folder because your project folder will be in the PYTHONPATH automatically when running via `manage.py runserver` or your wsgi script will point to it when running on production.

Usually all python packages are packaged like this:

```
package directory
    module directory
    ... other files/dirs like README, Manifest and so on
```

What need to be in your Django project folder is only the `module directory` part from the example above, not the rest of the package.

Comment: @Torsen - Thanks for a good answer. Right now python is Just Another Language for me and 1) I want to get hacking, 2) I want to hack like the django/python makers intended and 3) I want to improve and learn.

Comment: @Dizzley - Ok, but please consider Daniel Roseman answer below as well. I would say that's the more common and clean way than putting all your needed modules into the project folder.

Answer (score 2):

Use virtualenv.

That is by far the best solution for installing custom packages for each project.

Comment: virtualenv can create a closed python environment for you. That means for example python packages installed in your system PYTHONPATH will not affect the python installation and programs in your virtualenv. The advantage is for example that for each of your django projects you can install different dependencies in their respective virtualenv and they will not affect each other. That also includes different Django versions. Check http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: A vote-up for virtualenv then. The isolation has a number of benefits: your apps do not interfere with each other; you are protected from system wide changes; the system is protected from you. I suspect there is a downside: design and implementation fragmentation etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `--home` - nothing scary about it.

Don't forget to make your `PYTHONPATH` point there, though.

Comment: I might experiment in installing package this way.